# CSS opacity animation not working in any browser

Tags: html, css

2 hours in this code! I've tried to change everything I thought be wrong. Tried it in different browsers and nothing!

```css
@keyframes faden {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fatia {
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation: faden;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name: faden;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation: faden
}
```

```html
<div id="fatia1" class="fatia"> <img class="img-responsive" src="graficos/imagens/imagens/banner_imotur_servicos_01.jpg" /></div>
<div id="fatia2" class="fatia"><img class="img-responsive" src="graficos/imagens/imagens/banner_imotur_servicos_02.jpg" /></div>
<div id="fatia3" class="fatia"><img class="img-responsive" src="graficos/imagens/imagens/banner_imotur_servicos_03.jpg" /></div>
<div id="fatia4" class="fatia"><img class="img-responsive" src="graficos/imagens/imagens/banner_imotur_servicos_04.jpg" /></div>
<div id="fatia5" class="fatia"><img class="img-responsive" src="graficos/imagens/imagens/banner_imotur_servicos_05.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: try removing the `opacity: 0` from your `.fatia`

Comment: I've tried already and the page loads with images displaying but no animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your opacity is set to 0 on fatia.  This is making all of your images invisible.  Try using this for your class:

```
.fatia {
  animation: faden 4s linear;
  -webkit-animation: faden 4s linear;
}
```

Then add in moz, etc.

Also a quick note: If it seems that the images are loading, but not transitioning, try adding a delay to the animation.  Sometimes browser speed will alter the presentation of transitions.

Comment: It worked! Removing just opacity:0 I end up with the images with full opacity but no animation. But when I changed my css rule for exactly what you proposed it worked. I wonder what's the matter.

Comment: Great!  The problem probably was that you had "animation" instead of "animation-name" and you didn't have animation-duration outside of webkit.  For example, long-hand code of what I put above looks something like this:                                                                                     animation-name: faden;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-duration: 4s;

Comment: A good way to avoid this kind of problem is to start out developing in Chrome.  Chrome doesn't need browser preference tags to animate.  Once you have something working in chrome, then add browser-set editions :)